# Fruit Ninja Design Decisions

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I'm doing a Fruit Ninja clone in java (language not really relevant). It's not completed yet, but here is the point I'm in now:

Currently I've:

- `Difficulty` interface, where several classes will implement it to decide the fruit moving speed based on the game time, and also determine how many bombs will be created compared to fruits (the more bombs, the more difficult).
- `GameOverCondition` interface, where it's implemented by `ArcadeGameOverCondition` and `ClassicGameOverCondition`, because in Classic you lose when lives end. and in Arcade you lose when time is up.
- There is a `GameObject` abstract class that's extended by `Fruit` abstract class and `Bomb` abstract class. `Fruit` is extended by concrete fruit classes, and `Bomb` is extended by concrete different bombs.
- There is a `FruitNinja` class, which take `GameOverCondition` and `Difficulty` in the constructor. And in the constructor it will run a thread that constantly create more `GameObject`s. And each `GameObject` will run a thread in the constructor that moves it with the specific speed determined by the `Difficulty`.

At this point, I just noticed that `Difficulty` logic **currently** will be the **same** for all game types (arcade & classic) (which could be making the game faster and also increase number of bombs). However, I'm thinking that later I may want different logic. How should I change my design?

Feel free to tell any improvements you see.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some notes, starting with your question:

- Yes, you should change your design if you see you can get away with a simpler design. With every feature you build in you basically force yourself to maintain something without needing it. So, if you don't need an interface, don't have one. Introduce it only when you actually need it, even if you think it's tomorrow.
- `GameOverCondition` sounds wrong. It's technical. `ArcadeGame` and `ClassicGame` sound much better, I would also assign the responsibility for the whole game to these, not just the condition when it ends.
- I'm uneasy with the `GameObject` hierarchy. It's an inheritance tree, and inheritance is very difficult to get right. I would just go with interfaces and delegation unless there is a really good reason against it.
- You mention the speed and composition of objects is determined by `Difficulty` and based on that `FruitNinja` object will create `GameObjects`. Instead having a concept of speed, and what I assume are numbers about the composition, etc. why not have the `Difficulty` object directly create objects for the game? It has all the information it needs to do so, so it doesn't really make sense to publish that information, and let somebody else take action on it.

As always my general object-oriented rules apply:

- Don't have getters. It messes with your design, very seldom for the better.
- Have meaningful (i.e. domain-relevant) names for all public identifiers.

Comment: "why not have the `Difficulty` object directly create objects for the game?" because the `FruitNinja` class should be aware of them, I want the caller to be able to do: `fruitNinjaInstance.getObjects()` and it will return all the current objects.

Comment: and because `Fruit`s and `Bomb`s have similar behavior, I've implemented this behavior in a parent abstract class `GameObject`, what do you think?

Comment: And you didn't mention how to handle the different logic of difficulty based on the game type.